# find keys from value in nested dictionary in ios

Tags: ios, arrays, nsdictionary

I Have a nested Dictionary as follow:

```
Dict
{
    B =     {
        D =         (
            "X",
            "Y",
            Z,
            W,
        );
        DID =         (
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        );
        ID = 33;
    };
}
```

I have Only 33, How can I get the the key named **B**?

Help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: @Larme, I get 33 as `[[dict objectForKey:[[dict allKeys]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]objectForKey:@"ID"]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the keys of dictionary by using the method

```
[dict allKeys];
```

It will return an array of all the keys in your dictionary.

But in your case if want the keys of nested dictionaries too than according to me you should loop on the top level dictionary keys and then find all the keys of nested dictionaries using above methods. But for this you should be clear with your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse key and values which are dictionaries again.

[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {

```
NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, object);
```

}];